# learning the order of elements

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, ranking, reinforcement-learning

I have a list of elements with very little information about them. These elements are ordered and I need to find the correct order. All I can do is to submit a query with a hypothesizes complete order and get a score (between 0 and 1) which represents how far is my ordering from the true ordering, without any information about which part of the ordering is correct/incorrect.

This seems like a standard kind of a problem, but I couldn't find info about that.

EDIT: for simplicity, assume that the score of a given hypothesized ordering is the percentage of correct pair-ordering (compared to the real, unknown ordering). so you get a 0 if you are giving the reverse ordering, and 1 if you give the real ordering.
Is there a strategy/algorithm that can generate queries based on past answers to minimize learning time and maximize score achieved?

I thought that learning to rank algorithms should help, but their formulation seems far from what I need, although I might have missed something. I am also looking at some reinforcement learning algorithms

However, any references/hints/help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very hard problem. The general learning to order can be achieved with the approach of Deep-Q-Learning (like in the famous Atari-learning paper by deepmind; Q-learning=some RL-app) as it's a model-free learning-approach. Of course it's needed that there is something to learn (and can be grasped by the network-architecture). This learning will be done online and it will generate queries according to the currently learned stuff and improve the knowledge. **But** if you want to learn this with a minimal number of queries, a more bandit-theory driven learning-approach has to be designed.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a method on how to think of the problem.

You need to understand how the distance is calculated.  One way to think of this problem is as a problem in the space of combinations.  If you have *n* elements, then think of an n-dimensional space, where each point in the space represents an ordering of the elements.  One of these points is "correct" with the optimal score.

You have a distance metric from any (valid) point in the space to the given correct point.  The question is:  how can you find the "correct" answer.

It is possible that a gradient descent solution might work.  As applied to this problem, it would start at a random point, consider simple "steps" in various directions (by swapping values) and move in the direction that best improves the score.  The problem is that the solution space probably has local optima that are widely dispersed in the solution space, meaning that "local" methods (such as stepping) can get fooled by local optima.  But it might work.

An alternative might be a brute force like this.  Start with a vector of all zeros and measure its score.  Then test the first value in each position and choose the position that minimizes the score.  My hunch is that the scoring metric would be minimized when the value is in the right position.  Then, repeat for each other value.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point. When I query about a potential ordering I get only a number in response (say 0.6) How does this give me a direction where I should go and what should I change? while I can just try lot of swaps to see which gives the greates improvement, this seems like a very inefficient way that requires lots of queries.
for the question of how the score is calculated, see the edit above in the question

Comment: @amit The environment you describe is a typical black-box or derivative-free environment which makes this very complex problem even more complex (it also depends on how fast the evaluation is; if it's fast one could stick to finite-difference to approximate the gradient). Your post is also missing a lot of details. We don't even know if your scoring-procedure is even a **metric**. Again: for minimizing queries, look into bandit-theory. But well... still a very hard problem. And even if the whole learning-to-rank approaches do not fit (you don't explain why), it's a valuable ressource!

Comment: @amit . . . For instance, you could try all possible single swaps O(n^2) and then choose the swap that has the best effect on the score.